Maven command not working correctly on machine
So, I've been writing unit tests for some code, and I noticed they don't run correctly when I run Maven commands. I don't even get an error. It returns a whole bunch of lines. It seems it's looking for something. I have Java 21 and Maven version 3.9.9
This is what it returns when I run a simple command mvn -v.
usage: java [options] ,mainclass. [args....]
(to execute a class)
or java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args....]
(to execute a jar file)
or java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
(to execute the main class in a module)
or java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
(to execute a single source-file program)

Arguments following the main class, source file, -jar <jarfile>,
-m or --module <module>/<mainclass> are passed as the arguments to 
main class.
where options include:
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
--class-path <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives, 
and ZIP archives to search for class files.

I tried editing environment variables and reinstalling Maven. I also restarted the machine and had no luck. This is how I have set the env variables and my JAVA_HOME



On which kind of OS you are? If you just try to do mvn --version on plain command of your OS? What is the output... That looks like a call via java ... but not mvn ... ?

I am on windows. I tried that and i get the same output

In the CMD Box (so called DOS Box in windows)? How have you configured Maven to run? How have you set JAVA_HOME?

JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21 and MAVEN_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9

MAVEN_HOME is not relevant... only the entry in PATH variable... which needs to contain C:\..\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin ...

i have tried this already and still get the same response message

Can you show how you exactly set JAVA_HOME?

Just edited post to show how it is set

Run java -version from the CMD prompt and ensure the system finds it. Verify your path variable.
Can you the run following command and try
Set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
This would make sure that if there are multiple  java installation, your preferred installation gets picked up. This way there won't be any ambiguity.
Similarly, you can include %MAVEN_HOME%/bin in the path.

MAVEN_HOME is useless because it's not used anywhere...

I could see references of MAVEN_HOME in mvn.cmd..reference https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.9.9/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn.cmd , so there must be some use of this env variable.

Remove it. It's internally used... please remove it...

I dont remove facts. I have provided the data, it is upto you how you want to process it.

should i remove MAVEN_HOME?

As I wrote.. remove the entry for MAVEN_HOME... from your environment...

I removed it from environment and have the entry path set directly to C:\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin. Still getting the same error

Please try reinstalling Java. Maven is getting invoked properly, but the call to Java is failing. Then, please run echo %PATH% and share the result.
